# Is there a brief way to view the top resource usage(CPU, memory or even bandwidth) of a program after its running?

Tags: memory, monitoring, cpu, bandwidth

I know I can use `top` to view the overall real-time CPU & Memory usage,
and `nload` for overall real-time bandwidth usage.

But I wish to view the maximum(or average) CPU, Memory, & bandwidth usage of a program after its running.
Just like `time my_command` did in program time spend estimation.

Is there a brief way to do that in Linux/Unix?

Comment: There is a program thats called `htop` that provides a more graphical interpretation of `top`.. Not sure if it has everything your looking for but definitely worth investigating..

Answer (score 5):

If the system supports process accounting, and accounting is enabled, then there may be records available in the process accounting file, e.g. on RedHat Linux:

```
$ grep -q BSD_PROCESS_ACCT=y /boot/config-* && echo hooray
hooray
$ sudo touch /var/log/pacct
$ sudo accton /var/log/pacct
$
...
$ sudo accton   # turn it off
```

Parsing the `acct(5)` file is left as an exercise to the reader.

However, this is global, so may not be suitable for a system with a heavy load of new process creation. Per-process, the `getrusage(2)` call should yield CPU and memory stats, possibly via a wrapper with the `RUSAGE_CHILDREN` flag to report on child processes you are interested in.

Network bandwidth may be more difficult to obtain, especially on a per-process basis.

Other tools, such as DTrace or [Ftrace](http://lwn.net/Articles/608497/) may also be of interest.